# Magento - update order status via API

Tags: magento

I have added a custom order status option. 
Does anyone know how I can set it to my custom value via the API?

Comment: via Magento core API or with SOAP API?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to Diglin for pointing me in the right place. Just to present the answer properly:

You can do this by using the addComment method, which also lets you specify the new order status as one of it's parameters.

```
$sku='100000003';
$orderStatus = 'Downloaded';
$comment = 'The order was successfully downloaded';
$sendEmailToCustomer = false;

$proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order.addComment', array($sku, $orderStatus, $comment, $sendEmailToCustomer));
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

After to have seen the api doc and the source code, you can get only information about an order and add a comment to it. You cannot edit or delete an order. You have to create your own API if you need that.
See this link to see what is possible with the API: [Magento Core API - Mage Sales](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api#mage_sales)

Comment: Perfect it works - 
I was searching for a custom method and it was available all along as part of addComment.
`$proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order.addComment', array('100000003', 'mycustomvalue', 'A custom comment', true));`

Comment: I was thinking that addComment, add only comment :-) but you can add more. great :-)