# How to confirm an order in Magento using the SOAP webservice?

Tags: magento, soap

I'm trying to confirm an order using the Magento web-service. I can put an order on hold like this:

```
$result = $client->salesOrderHold( $sessionId, $order_id );
echo "Order on Hold: " . $result . "<br>";
```

or add a comment to the order, but I can't find the function to call to confirm an order.

NOTE: my orders are being confirmed manually, so, I need to do this using the web service.

any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have responded to almost the same question here [Update order status via API][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819979/magento-update-order-status-via-api

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw that reply before and already tried it... but when I add a comment with "Confirmed" as the status... it changes... but the order is still NOT recognized as "confirmed"... in the Magento orders list... the status field for the order is empty and when I open the order... I still can see the "confirm" button at the top of that order... which means that Magento doesn't recognize this as a confirmed order. I used the status text "confirmed"... is this the correct text to use for the status?

Comment: no the status must be "complete" when the order is done

Comment: But, after I confirm the order, the order will not be in "complete" status. You see, in our model, the order is received, then, we confirm it manually, then, we'll ship it and modify the order status accordingly. So, I can't use the "complete" status. What I'm trying to find out based on your link above is the status text that I should use to make the order confirmed. Do you know what the status that I should use?

Answer (score 1):

From Magento version 1.4.2, the status of an order can be customized. So now, you have two kind of value for a status order. Check this link to see what is possible and what are the differences between state and status. [Magento state and status](http://blog.baobaz.com/en/tag/magento-state-and-status)

I am not sure of what you are expecting by setting your order to "confirm". If it's just a display needs, you can create yours in backend menu System > Order Statuses. Then you can use the API to addComment with your customized status or an existing one but it won't change the state of the order. It will stay in "On Hold" if it is in this state.

If you want to change the state and not the status, you need to extend the api of the module `Mage_Sales` to allow to set a status to an order. Magento doesn't offer it by default. As it is written in the link provided in my comment, you cannot edit the status and a state of an order. The method `addComment` of the API doesn't change the state, it allows only to change the status in the comment. You have to create your method based on the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api`. See the following link to do it by yourself [Create a custom API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/custom-api)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the hint and apologies for my late response. I've been reassigned again to this just today. I've used the link
you've sent me earlier to successfully -confirm- an order using API, but not through SOAP.

This is the code, hopefully, it may help someone else:

`$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId( $id );
$state = 'processing';
$status = 'Confirmed';
$comment = 'Changing state to Processing and status to Confirmed';
$isCustomerNotified = false;
$order->setState( $state, $status, $comment, $isCustomerNotified );
$order->save();`